# AOR: How to route to edit page when user click on a Datagrid row?

Tags: admin-on-rest

**Background**

I'm using the [Admin on rest Datagrid](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#the-datagrid-component) component to render a REST endpoint. Like this:

```
<Datagrid>
    <TextField source="name" />
    <TextField source="email" />
    <EditButton />        
</Datagrid>
```

The EditButton routes the User to the corresponding edit page. All works great.

**Question**

But now I'm trying to work out how to route the user to the edit page on row click instead, without using the EditButton.

**My attempts**

My first idea was to use the rowOption `onCellClick`.

```
<Datagrid rowOptions={ {onClick: rowClick } } >
    <TextField source="name" />
    <TextField source="email" />
</Datagrid>
```

where the handle function looks like this.

```
const rowClick = (proxy, event) => {
    console.log(proxy, event);
    // how to get the resource id??
}
```

This captures the row click, and the event data is logged to the console. But as far as I can see the click event data doesn't contain information about the REST resource id of the row.

Has someone used the row click event to do something similar?

Or would a better approach be create a new component (for example `ClickableField`) to wrap the TextField's and add click event handlers in this wrapping component? Like so:

```
<Datagrid>
    <ClickableField><TextField source="name" /></ClickableField>
    <ClickableField><TextField source="email" /></ClickableField>
</Datagrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material UI table property has an onRowSelection property. You can use this to define and set custom actions when row is selected

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table

You can access these properties in the 'options' prop of the AOR datagrid.

If this fails your clickable field idea should work.

Answer (score 4):

As replied by kunal pareek, the accepted answer suggesting to use `onRowSelection` worked.

Initially I missed the `selectable` property passed to the TableRow. But when I added that, the selection event was handled. Thus I ended up with this.

```
<Datagrid rowOptions={{ selectable: true }} options={{ onRowSelection: rowClick }}>
    <TextField source="name" />
    <TextField source="email" />
</Datagrid>
```